# PhantomJS My code won't click or run a click even

Tags: javascript, click, phantomjs

I am trying to run the on click function SelectPlaystation4 (8th from the bottom).  Is PhantomJS able to do this?  How can I do this in phantomjs?  I have been trying to use evaluate from the docs... with out any luck

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix">        

    <section class="content" style="margin-bottom: 35px;">          

      <div id="col-main" class="clearfix">
```

```
<div class="col-md-12 console-ps">
    <div class="collection-details text-center">
      <h3>
        Playstation
      </h3>
      <div class="line"></div>
       <!--<a href="#" class="col-btn btn">PS3</a>-->
       <input type="button" class="col-btn btn" onclick="SelectPlaystation4()" value="Playstation 4">
       <input type="button" class="col-btn btn" onclick="SelectPlaystation3()" value="Playstation 3">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 console-xb">
    <div class="collection-details text-center">
```

Comment: I don't see your code, so I'm closing as a duplicate of the general clicking question.

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` function doesn't create a click it is just a `click handler` causing something else to happen when a click is made.

For what you are trying to achieve you need to look into the Phantomjs `sendEvent`.  You can find those [docs here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html).

From the docs:

> **Mouse events**
>
> `sendEvent(mouseEventType[, mouseX, mouseY, button='left'])`
>
> The first argument is the event type. Supported types are `'mouseup'`,
>   `'mousedown'`, `'mousemove'`, `'doubleclick'` and `'click'`. The next two
>   arguments are optional but represent the mouse position for the event.
>
> The button parameter (defaults to `left`) specifies the button to push.
>
> For `'mousemove'`, however, there is no button pressed (i.e. it is not
>   dragging).

Comment: page.sendEvent('click', ['200px', '540px', button='left']);  Still not working... can't seem to get this to work (also tried with numbers, instead of strings)